# How was this central difference formula calculated?

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

My textbook is talking about using the central difference formula derived from the Taylor series to estimate a first order derivative. It uses the example:

$$f(x+h)-f(x-h)=2{h\over 1!}f'(x)+2{h^3\over 3!}f'''(x)+odd\; terms$$
$$f'(x)={{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}\over 2h}+O(h^2)$$ where $O(h^2)$ is the lowest order of the denominator. I understand where this came from and I worked it out for myself to be sure. However the textbook goes on to say

> Clearly we do not have to stop here. Instead of one point on each side of $x$, we can take several, for instance at $x-2h$, $x-h$, $x+h$, and $x+2h$.

I don't really understand what this means, I know it has something to do with step size to increase accuracy, but I can't figure out exactly what's trying to be explained. The example that they give doesn't really explain very much. Here it is:
$$f'(x)={1\over 12h}(f(x-2h)-8f(x-h)+8f(x+h)-f(x+2h))+O(h^4)$$

I also tried working this out for myself, by subtracting terms on the right and isolating $f'(x)$, but it was an enormous mess and I had lots of factorials that I didn't know what to do with. I also don't know where the $12h$ came from in the denominator. Can someone tell me what happened here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to find a better approximation of $f'(x)$ by using four instead of two values. Note that
$$f(x+h)-f(x-h) = 2hf'(x)+\frac{2h^3}{3!}f^{(3)}(x)+\frac{2h^5}{5!}f^{(5)}(x)+ \cdots \tag 1$$
Consequently,
$$f(x+2h)-f(x-2h) = 4hf'(x)+\frac{16h^3}{3!}f^{(3)}(x)+\frac{64h^5}{5!}f^{(5)}(x)+ \cdots \tag 2$$
In order to improve the accuracy of the approximation, we try to eliminate the $h^3$ terms using $(1)$ and $(2)$. That can be achieved if we multiply both sides of $(1)$ by $8$ and subtract $(2)$ from it. In particular, multiplication of $(1)$ by $8$ results in
$$8(f(x+h)-f(x-h)) = 16h f'(x)+ \frac{16h^3}{3!}f^{(3)}(x)+\frac{16h^5}{5!}f^{(5)}(x)+ \cdots \tag 3$$
Now subtract $(2)$ from $(3)$ to get
$$8(f(x+h-f(x-h))-(f(x+2h)-f(x-2h)) = 12h f'(x) + O(h^5).$$